# Extract multiple substrings from very long line

Tags: linux, string, shell

I have very long line of text in format:

```
http://address1/user1=username1;ip1=ipaddres1;password1=pass1;some text;http://address2/user2=username2;ip2=ipaddress2;password2=pass2;some text;...etc
```

How I can extract usernames (part after user1=, user2=) and ip addresses (part after ip1=, ip2=) from this line (in line have more than 20 usernames and ip addresses) and put them in two files (user.txt, ip.txt)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` to find the matching parts and `cut` to remove the stuff before `=`:

```
grep -o 'user[0-9]=[^;]*' input.txt | cut -d= -f2- > user.txt
grep -o 'ip[0-9]=[^;]*'   input.txt | cut -d= -f2- > ip.txt
```

`-o` only prints the matching parts. If there are several matches on the same line, they are printed to separate lines.

Comment: Excellent! Just I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`: To store into separate files:

```
gawk -v RS='some text' '{$1=$1;match($0,/user[0-9]+=([^;]+).*ip[0-9]+=([^;]+).*/,a);print a[1]>"username";print a[2] > "ipaddress"}' long_file

cat username
username1
username2


cat ipaddress
ipaddres1
ipaddress2
```

This `awk` assumes that between each records there is `some text` is present.

Or using `grep` with `-P`:

```
grep -oP 'user[0-9]+=\K[^;]+' long_file > username
grep -oP 'ip[0-9]+=\K[^;]+' long_file >ip_address
```